# How to enable external storage(sd card) saving for application?

Tags: java, android, sd-card

How to enable external storage(sd card) saving for application ?
Hi, we would like to know what permissions do we need to add, so users can transfer our applications to their external storage (sd card).

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500839/moving-to-sd-card

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to add the **WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** permission to your **manifest** file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```